# Variable value as yaml key in helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I want to choose config section from values.yaml by setting a variable in helm command line.

example part of values.yaml:

```
aaa:
  x1: "az1"
  x2: "az2"
bbb:
  x1: "bz1" 
  x2: "bz2"
```

example part of configmap.yaml

```
data: 
  {{ .Values.outsideVal.x1 }}
```

Expected result should looks like this

```
   data:
     az1
```

Test helm output

```
helm template --set outsideVal=aaa mychart
```

And got this error

```
Error: render error in "./templates/configmap.yaml": template: ./templates/configmap.yaml:21:12: executing "./templates/configmap.yaml" at <.Values.outsideVal.x...>: can't evaluate field x1 in type interface {}
```

So the question is how get the result as expected?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect you're looking for the [text/template](https://godoc.org/text/template) `index` function, which can look up a value in a map by a variable key.

```
{{ (index .Values .Values.outsideVal).x1 }}
```

Comment: Does this actually work?  The docs say that `index` is for numeric indexing into a list (i.e. array), not string indexing into a map/dict

Comment: "Each indexed item must be a map, slice, or array."