# How can I do this in a Helm chart's values.yaml file?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

We deploy our microservices in multiple AWS regions. I therefore want to be able to do this in a Helm chart `values.yaml` file.

```yaml
# Default region
aws_region: us-east-1

aws_ecrs:
  us-east-1: 01234567890.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
  eu-north-1: 01234567890.dkr.ecr.eu-nort-1.amazonaws.com

image:
  name: microservice0
  repository: {{ .Values.aws_ecrs.{{ .Values.aws_region }} }} # I know this is incorrect
```

So now when I install the chart, I just want to do

```
$ helm install microservice0 myChart/ --set aws_region=eu-north-1
```

and the appropriate repository will be assigned to `.Values.image.repository`. Can I do this? If so what is the correct syntax?

NOTE: The image repository is just one value that depends on the AWS region, we have many more other values that also depend on the AWS region.

Comment: I have a feeling this is what I need so I'm trying to make it work for me. https://itnext.io/reference-other-values-in-helm-chart-values-file-19d44d9276c7

Answer (score -1):

Pass the repository name as an ordinary Helm value.

```yaml
# templates/deployment.yaml
image: {{ .Values.repository }}/my-image:{{ .Values.tag }}
```

Create a separate file per region.  This does not necessarily need to be in the same place as the Helm chart.  Provide the regional values as ordinary top-level values.  You'll have multiple files that provide the same values and that's fine.

```yaml
# eu-north-1.yaml
repository: 01234567890.dkr.ecr.eu-nort-1.amazonaws.com
```

Then when you deploy the chart, use the `helm install -f` option to use the correct per-region values.  These values will override anything in the chart's `values.yaml` file, but anything you don't specifically set here will use those default values from the chart.

```bash
helm install microservice0 myChart/ \
  --set-string tag=20220201 \
  -f eu-north-1.yaml
```

You can in principle use the Go template `index` function to do the lookup as you describe; the top-level structure in [Variable value as yaml key in helm chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52407940/variable-value-as-yaml-key-in-helm-chart) is similar to what you show in the question.  This is more complex to implement in the templating code, though, and it means you have different setups for the values that must vary per region and those that can't.

Comment: Thanks I'll use the first part of your answer. I don't really want "multiple files that provide the same values" advice since if I have to change some value, I'll now have to change multiple files. Sure it can be scripted but that's beside the point.

Comment: You can have multiple `helm install -f` values files, and the chart's `values.yaml` is still considered as well.  So with this approach you'd have to edit a file per environment for the values that are different per environment, but you can change the chart's `values.yaml` for values that are the same across all environments.

Comment: After reading this answer again, it doesn't answer my question at all, but thanks!